# Notify Qt Window when its visibility status has changed

Tags: c++, qt

How can I notify a Qt Window when its visibility status has changed?

Example Use Case:

1. User goes from Window A (hide) to Window B (show)
2. User returns to Window A (show) from Window B (hide)

I want to invoke a function when Window A changes from (hide) to (show).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the

```
void visibilityChanged(QWindow::Visibility visibility)
```

signal as stated in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html#visibility-prop) to be notified of a QWindow visibility status change.